# Unique content identifier with Selenium: InvalidSelectorError

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab data from: http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/de/etfs/ishares+msci+world+momentum+factor+ucits+etf+DE000A12BHF2

The types of data I'm looking for are located in the classes named `singlebox list_component`. Let's say I want to extract the Total Expense Ratio (0.30%). It is located in a `td class` called: `right column-datavalue lastColOfRow`.

But if I do:

```
dues = driver.find_element_by_class_name("right column-datavalue lastColOfRow ")
expense_ratio = re.search(r"(.{4})(?=%)", dues.text).group(0).encode("utf-8")
```

I get:

```
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
```

And adding to this problem, there seem to be multiple instances of `right column-datavalue lastColOfRow` so it doesn't serve as an unique identifier.

*Note*: If this problem is better solved with `BeautifulSoup` instead of `Selenium`, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_element_by_css_selector()` instead to match element by multiple CSS classes :

```
dues = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".right.column-datavalue.lastColOfRow")
```

but as you claimed that the above selector isn't unique, you can use xpath to match those CSS classes considering the order (I found this xpath is unique on that web page) :

```
xpath = "//td[@class='right column-datavalue lastColOfRow']"
dues = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Another way to approach this using xpath is by selecting `<td>` element that follows another `<td>` containing text `Gesamtkostenquote` :

```
xpath = "//td[@class='column-datacaption' and normalize-space(text())='Gesamtkostenquote']/following-sibling::td"
dues = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like elegant solutions. But when trying the two alternatives, I get error messages. Any idea why? **Alt 1:** `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":".right.column-datavalue.lastColOfRow”}` **Alt 2:** `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[@class='column-datacaption' and normalize-space(text())='Gesamtkostenquote']/following-sibling::td"}`

Comment: @Winterflags there was copy-paste error from my side for **Alt 1**, the method should've been `find_element_by_css_selector` instead of `find_element_by_class_name`. I don't have selenium installed, all suggested xpath & css selector only tested using firefox extension, firepath

Comment: I did notice the copy-paste error, but I fixed it before. The error messages seem to be unrelated. I will have to look into this a bit further. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Btw, I assumed you're using `find_element_by_class_name` because of this part of the error message `... {"method":"class name"...`. No surprise though if that isn't the case, since I'm not selenium expert..